# Class has not been declared error message in C++

Tags: c++, class, codeblocks

So this code was given to me to run, and whenever I try to run it, I get the same error message. "English class has not been declared".
I'm fairly new to C++ so anything helps.
Currently, I'm using the program CodeBlocks to run my code. When I received the error message, I then copied and pasted it into my DevC++ editor and got the same problem.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Metric {
int meters;
int centis;
public:
       Metric(int m, int cm)
         {
             meters = m; centis = cm;
         }
        Metric( void ) { meters = centis = 0; }

      void ShowMetricData(void)
         {
           cout << "Metric object: meters = " << meters;
           cout << " centimeters = " << centis << "\n\n";
          }


friend class English;
friend bool compare(Metric, English);


};   // code for class English follows this code



class English {
           int  inches, feet;
    public:

 // ‘Default Constructor
         English(void) { feet = 0; inches =  0; }

  // ‘Initializing Constructor
         English(int ft, int in) { feet = ft; inches = in; }

  //  Prototype for a Constructor that converts a
  //    Metric instance  into an English instance
         English(Metric);

  // Prototype for an operator function that converts
  //   an English  instance into a Metric instance
         operator Metric( void );
         friend bool compare(Metric, English);
         };


    /English::operator Metric( )
    // {
    //   Metric MObj;
    //   float MLgth, ELgth;
    //   ELgth = feet * 12 + inches;
    //   MLgth = 2.54 * ELgth;
    //   MObj.meters = (int) ( MLgth / 100.0);
    //   MObj.centis = (int) (MLgth - MObj.meters*100);
    //   cout << "In operator function Metric that converts English ==> Metric: \n\n";
    //   cout << " English object: feet = " << feet
    //              << " and inches = " << inches << "\n\n";
    //   cout << " Metric object: meters  = " << MObj.meters
    //                  << " cms = " << MObj.centis << "\n\n";
    //   return MObj;
    //  }
    //
    //
    // English::English(Metric Met_Obj)
    //{
    //  float MetL, EngL;
    //  MetL = 100.0 * Met_Obj.meters + Met_Obj.centis;
    //  EngL = MetL / 2.54;
    //
    //  feet = (int) ( EngL / 12.0) ;
    //  inches = (int) ( EngL - 12*feet);
    //
    //  cout << "In constructor English(Metric) that converts Metric=>English: \n\n";
    //  cout << " Metric object: meters = " << Met_Obj.meters << " and cms = "<<       Met_Obj.centis << "\n\n";
    //  cout << " feet = " << feet << " inches = " << inches  << "\n\n";
    //}
    //
    //bool compare (Metric mObj, English eObj)
    //   {
    //       float EobjLength;
    //       float MobjLength;
    //
    //       EobjLength = eObj.feet * 12 + eObj.inches;
    //
    //       MobjLength = mObj.meters * 100 + mObj.centis;
    //
    //       if( MobjLength  > EobjLength * 2.54)
    //          return true;
    //       else
    //          return false;
    //}

/


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       English EngObj(8, 11);
       Metric MetObj(EngObj);

     //<<<<<<<<<< CODE BLOCK A >>>>>>>>>>>
         if(compare( EngObj,MetObj) )
           {
             cout << "\n\n Metric object is larger\n\n";
             }
          else
             cout << "English object is larger \n\n";
      // <<<<<<<<< END OF CODE BLOCK A >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        system("PAUSE");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: /English::operator Metric( ), Add double slash here and try again

Comment: uncomment your commented section and add `class English;` before class Metric.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare class English before using it as friends in Metric class.
2. Metric MetObj(EngObj); to achieve this declare a constructor in Metric class which takes English as input; Metric(const Enlish& rhs){}
3. implement compare func properly and have right arguments sent in right order.
    As compare func suggest input as Metirc, English while in main you invoke compare(English,Metric). 
   If you want to do so then implement a converter to have this working. BUT why would you want to do so, when things can be done neatly.